# JavaScript formatting time 24hours format to 12hours

Tags: java, javascript, string, substr

I was having some trouble when trying to format time in 24 hours format to 12 hours format. Here are some of the example of my time in string format:

```
0:00, 9:00, 12:00, 15:00
```

I wonder how should I substr the first two character in JavaScript because some of them were one digit and some were two. The output time format should be in 12 hours format like:

```
12:00AM, 9:00AM, 12:00PM, 3:00PM
```

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you have a single string with several times in it? Also, why the "java" tag?

Comment: Yeah the times are in string format.

Comment: Yes, but one string per time separated with commas, or a single string with four times in it? Either way, if you want to use string manipulation functions to extract the parts you can use a regular expression or `.split()` on the `:` character rather than trying to use `.substr()` with a fixed length.

Comment: Oh no no, one string at a time. Do you have any example for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you clarified that each string you process will have only a single time in it (i.e., you are not processing a single string with four comma-separated times in it). So essentially you have input as follows:

```
var input = "9:00";
```

The easiest way to extract the hour and minute is using the String [`.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). This splits up the string at a specified character - in your case you'd use `":"` - and returns an array with the pieces:

```
var parts = input.split(":"),
    hour = parts[0],
    minute = parts[1];
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Did not thought of the .split(). It was much more easier for conversion after split them into hour and minute :)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to use regular expressions (but remember AWZ's rule: if you have a problem and decide it can be solved with RE's, then you now have two prolems).

However, save yourself a whole helluva lot of trouble and get [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: But if using this moment.js, under which category that I should implement for this case? Is it format Dates??